# find relative maximum in graph function

Tags: functions, maxima-minima

> [image]
>   Find relative maximum in the graph above

For me, the answers are zero and two, but according to the correctness of the exam, the answer is incorrect

Comment: It is in Portugese or Spanish so I am not exactly sure what it is asking. However, it seems like it is asking about local maxima and $x=5$ is also a local maximum.

Comment: The question is in Spanish.

Answer (score 1):

Local maxima $x$ of a function $f$ are points such that $f(x)\geq f(y)$ for all $y\in(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)$. You can modify the definition a little bit to fit at the ends of the interval.

You correctly identified $x=0$ and $x=2$. In addition to those, $x=5$ is a local maximum since $f(5)\geq f(y)$ for all $y\in (5-\varepsilon,5]$.

Comment: For x=5,  it does not meet the definition, because 5 must be in an open interval, why should I consider 5 in a closed interval on the right? Shouldn’t it be an open interval at both ends?

Comment: At the ends of the interval, no! Otherwise, for example, extreme value theorem wouldn't make sense. Also trivially, $(5-\varepsilon,5]\subset(5-\varepsilon,5+\varepsilon)$. It is just that $f$ is not defined in $(5,5+\varepsilon)$ so we have to remove that part as it doesn't make sense to consider it to begin with.